# Check if value is in undefined enum?

Tags: c, enums

I am working on a file that runs on different processors, so the header files change based on the hardware. My program needs to receive an index and, if it is a valid index for a particular enum, use it, otherwise go to a default value.

I need to check if it is a valid index for this enum. HOWEVER, the enum is slightly different processor to processor. I have a header file for each chip, so I don't know how many indices are defined. Here is what it approximately looks like:

```
typedef enum
    {
    POWER_LEVEL_0
    POWER_LEVEL_1,
    POWER_LEVEL_2,
    POWER_LEVEL_3,
    POWER_LEVEL_4
    } power_type;
```

and I need to be able to test if a received index is defined, like so:

```
int input;
...
if( exists_in_power_type(input) )
    //accept the value
else
    //use default value
```

I know the number of indices will be in the range of about 4 to 7, and that may grow if I run this project on a new processor that may have 8 or more power options. In this case I want my program to be portable and only have to define an enum of the same name in a new header for that processor.

This problem may be a little easier because the enum values just start at 0 and increment by 1. Is there a way to get the length/max value of an enum without knowing its definition? Is there a similar work around that I could use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no cross-platform way to determine the maximum legal enumerated value for a particular `enum`. However, you can get around this by introducing a dummy enumerated value that comes after all the others:

```
typedef enum
{
    POWER_LEVEL_0
    POWER_LEVEL_1,
    POWER_LEVEL_2,
    POWER_LEVEL_3,
    POWER_LEVEL_4,
    ILLEGAL_POWER_LEVEL // Not to be used directly; must be last
} power_type;
```

Now, you can write your helper function as follows:

```
bool exists_in_power_type(power_type value) {
    return 0 <= value && value < ILLEGAL_POWER_LEVEL;
}
```

As long as `ILLEGAL_POWER_LEVEL` is the last of the enumerated values, this approach will check whether you have something assigned to `value` that matches some enumeration.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I usually call the dummy value something like `NUM_POWER_LEVELS`, since it would otherwise not be clear where someone should add a new power level.